# What is an asteroid called if it is in deep space?

Tags: asteroids, definition

Pretty much every definition I've read about asteroids is something like "Asteroids are rocky worlds revolving around the sun that are too small to be called planets."

What would an asteroid be called if it was in deep space, not orbiting any sun?

Comment: you might find this interesting as well, though only slightly related: [Do astronomers generally agree that the distinction between comets and astroids is not so clear?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19963/7982)

Comment: @uhoh That is interesting. According to the answer, asteroids aren't even a correct term anymore.

Comment: Anything you like - it can't hear you... :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have only discovered one such object so far: ʻOumuamua. (Although a second, 2I/Borisov, was discovered in 2019) The general practice has been to call it an "interstellar asteroid" or "interstellar comet", even though it is not in orbit.  You could just call it an "interstellar object".

Comment: Rogue asteroid would work too, at least, people would know what you mean, but I prefer the preface interstellar than rogue in this case.