# C-Type Asteroids and Carbonaceous Chondrite Meteorites

Tags: asteroids, space, meteor

I was just wondering, what is the relationship between C-type asteroids and carbonaceous chondrite (CC) meteorites? Do CC meteorites come from C-type asteroids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between asteroids, comets and meteors is discussed in [What is the difference between asteroids, comets and meteors?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/213/what-is-the-difference-between-asteroids-comets-and-meteors?rq=1)

Some [groupings of asteroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_spectral_types) have been correlated with meteorite types:

> C-type – Carbonaceous chondrite meteorites
>   S-type – Stony meteorites
>   M-type – Iron meteorites
>   V-type – HED meteorites

The S- and C-type asteroid classifications originate from the taxonomy proposed by [David Tholen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_J._Tholen).

Meteors are generally considered to be asteroids which enter Earth's atmosphere. 
Meteorites are meteor remnants which reach the ground. So essentially, carbonaceous chondrite meteor(ite)s start out as C-type asteroids; they're made of the same stuff.